# Executing Java application that makes a JNI call, with eclipse, fails with UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have a Java program that calls a function in a JNI library. The JNI code statically loads another shared library.

When executing the Java application using Eclipse, I get an error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ... Can't find dependent libraries

But, if i execute the same command in commandline, the program works fine. What am I doing wrong in Eclipse?

I made sure to go to Debug View -> Processs -> Process Properties to get the same command string and same working directory as Eclipse execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a PD procedure that might help you identify the problem.

Add the following to your program to identify the differences in the arch and load paths between the two runtime environments.  Investigate any differences in path/arch.

```
 System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
 System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));
```

You can use the dumpbin.exe utility to identify the dependencies needed by the DLL that is being loaded.
Make sure the dependencies exist.
Example usage:

```
C:> dumpbin /imports your.dll 

Dump of file your.dll
File Type: DLL
  Section contains the following imports:
    **KERNEL32.dll**
```

You can use the where.exe command to find the location of the dependencies.
Example usage:

```
C:>where KERNEL32.dll
    C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll
```

If you see:

```
C:>where KERNEL32.dll
    INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)
```

Investigate why the dependent DLL is not on the path.

You can use the dumpbin.exe command to check 64bit vs 32bit.
Example:

```
C:>dumpbin /headers yourd.dll

 Dump of file yourd.dll
 PE signature found
 File Type: DLL
 FILE HEADER VALUES
         14C machine (x86)    <-- 32bit DLL

C:>dumpbin /headers yourd.dll

 Dump of file yourd.dll
 PE signature found
 File Type: DLL
 FILE HEADER VALUES
         8664 machine (x64)    <-- 64bit DLL
```

Investigate any 32bit vs 64bit mismatches between main/dependent.  If your JVM is 32bit, you need to use 32bit DLLs.  If your JVM is 64bit, you need to use 64bit DLLs.  ( It is okay to run a 32bit JVM on a 64bit OS but the JNI DLLs must be 32bit ( DLLs match the JVM not the OS ).